# AmCharts not displayed when adding website to local IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, amcharts

I created asp.net webform project including amcharts using visual studio. Everything works when I run project. But when I publish it on a local IIS (current version is 7 - windows 7 64 bit) it is not displayed. I googled a bit but not found a solution yet. (One of them was Setting up IIS for correctly handling SVG files, but it also didn't help.) Is anybody faced this problem?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you exporting the charts to SVG files and then loading them in the page? If that is the case, you need to add the extension for IIS to support it. Check a bit more about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx

Comment: I create chart inside <div> tag.

Comment: What are the DivElement dimensions? Try to set it to be something like <div style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>

Comment: <div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 400px; height: 1000px; position: absolute; top: 260px; left: 40px; border: 2px solid #9ccfed;"></div>

Comment: Have you seen it working in any browser other than IE? Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome. When I run project it works. But not works after deploying to IIS.

Here is code I reduced additional parts.

Visual basic.Net code that gets data from SQL and creates string of JS function

```
    Protected Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    comm.CommandText = "Select DateMeasr, data1, data2 from dbo.Measurements where DateMeasr>'2017-06-13 12:04:30' and DateMeasr<'2017-06-13 17:00:00' Order by DateMeasr"
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Open()
    da.Fill(dtC)
    If dtC.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        DataCollect()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DataCollect()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim strtime As DateTime
    sb.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    sb.Append("function generateChartData() {")
    For i = 0 To dtC.Rows.Count - 1
        strtime = CDate(dtC.Rows(i).Item(0))
        sb.Append("var newDate = new Date(" + strtime.Year.ToString + ", " + (strtime.Month - 1).ToString + ", " + strtime.Day.ToString + ", " + strtime.Hour.ToString + ", " + strtime.Minute.ToString + ", " + strtime.Second.ToString + ");")
        sb.Append("var data1 = " + dtC.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString + ";")
        sb.Append("var data2 = " + dtC.Rows(i).Item(2).ToString + ";")
        sb.Append("chartData1.push({")
        sb.Append("date: newDate,")
        sb.Append("data1: data1,")
        sb.Append("data2: data2")
        sb.Append("});")
    Next
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btn1, btn1.GetType, "teststring", sb.ToString, False)
End Sub
```

Javascript function to create Amchart

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
       var chart1;
       var chartData1 = [];

       AmCharts.ready(function () {
  
           chart1 = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
           chart1.dataProvider = chartData1;
           chart1.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD, JJ:NN:SS";
           chart1.categoryField = "date";
           chart1.rotate = true;
           chart1.autoMargins = false;
           chart1.marginLeft = 85;
           chart1.marginTop = 200;
           chart1.pathToImages = "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";
 
           chart1.synchronizeGrid = true; // this makes all axes grid to be at the same intervals

           // AXES
           // category
           var categoryAxis1 = chart1.categoryAxis;
           categoryAxis1.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
           categoryAxis1.minPeriod = "ss";
           categoryAxis1.minorGridEnabled = true;
           categoryAxis1.axisColor = "#DADADA";
           categoryAxis1.twoLineMode = true;
           categoryAxis1.dateFormats = [{
               period: 'fff',
               format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
           }, {
               period: 'ss',
               format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
           }, {
               period: 'mm',
               format: 'JJ:NN'
           }, {
               period: 'hh',
               format: 'JJ:NN'
           }, {
               period: 'DD',
               format: 'DD'
           }, {
               period: 'WW',
               format: 'DD'
           }, {
               period: 'MM',
               format: 'MMMM'
           }, {
               period: 'YYYY',
               format: 'YYYY'
           }];

           // first value axis (on the left)
           var valueAxis1 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
           valueAxis1.offset = 175;
           valueAxis1.position = "right";
           valueAxis1.axisColor = "#04a016";
           valueAxis1.axisThickness = 2;
           chart1.addValueAxis(valueAxis1);

           var valueAxis2 = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
           valueAxis2.offset = 125;
           valueAxis2.position = "right";
           valueAxis2.axisColor = "#ea0e19";
           valueAxis2.axisThickness = 2;
           chart1.addValueAxis(valueAxis2);

           // GRAPHS
           // first graph
           var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
           graph1.valueAxis = valueAxis1; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
           graph1.lineColor = valueAxis1.axisColor;
           graph1.title = "data1graph";
           graph1.valueField = "data1";
           graph1.hideBulletsCount = 30;
           graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 1;
           graph1.lineThickness = 2;
           chart1.addGraph(graph1);

           var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
           graph2.valueAxis = valueAxis2; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
           graph2.lineColor = valueAxis2.axisColor;
           graph2.title = "data2graph";
           graph2.valueField = "data2";
           graph2.hideBulletsCount = 30;
           graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 1;
           graph2.lineThickness = 2;
           chart1.addGraph(graph2);

           // CURSOR
           var chartCursor1 = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
           chartCursor1.cursorAlpha = 0.1;
           chartCursor1.fullWidth = true;
           chartCursor1.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
           chart1.addChartCursor(chartCursor1);

           // SCROLLBAR
           var chartScrollbar1 = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
           chart1.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar1);

           // LEGEND
           var legend1 = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
           legend1.markerLabelGap = 3;
           legend1.spacing = 1;
           legend1.position = "absolute";
           legend1.position = "top";
           chart1.addLegend(legend1);

       });

       function clicktodrawchart() 
  {
           generateChartData();
           chart1.write("chartdiv1");
        }
</script>
```

Asp.net tags for buttons and div that show chart

```html
<div>
  <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Charts<br />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                <br />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="Get data from DB" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
    <input id="btnforchart" value="Click to draw charts" type="button" style="color: black; font-size:15px; padding:4px;" onclick="clicktodrawchart()" />
    <div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 400px; height: 1000px; position: absolute; top: 260px; left: 40px; border: 2px solid #9ccfed;"></div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
     </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    </div>
```